# How to get started with Simian and Munki

Tags: simian

I'm working with these two apps but have little to no experience in this area (or real world programming at all). I'd like to dive in but I'm not really sure where to start.

I understand that [Simian](https://github.com/google/simian/wiki/Admin-Setup) and [Munki](https://github.com/munki/munki/wiki) are used to deploy and monitor software.

What would building a deployment, for example, Google Chrome look like?

Comment: "When you want to learn how to swim, first hang around the pool and *watch* the swimmers." In this case, surf to places like GitHub (and, do a thorough search on the various SO-family sites) to find *existing code projects* that use these tools.  Download their source-code and then, "tear 'em apart." Look at how they're put together. Look at how they handle Chrome. Look at how they (in their documentation, READMEs, and in their actual code) handle deployment. These aren't "toy" examples: these are *real apps* that their generous authors have shared with the world ... and, with you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have been toying around with it all day and understand it a tad more but am still fairly lost. My mentor will give me some assistance this afternoon.